# Undefined method `new' for true:TrueClass when precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4, everything goes prettey when until I deploy to heroku.

When runnning `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, it reports:

```
I, [2014-01-10T22:10:42.350746 #14896]  INFO -- : Writing F:/Sites/reachable/pub
lic/assets/rails-bac5a56948f29ccb6a93b0d2a5d10cf2.png
rake aborted!
undefined method `new' for true:TrueClass
  (in F:/Sites/reachable/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

I guess it has something to do with assets precompling configs, but unable to find the solution to it.
This is part of my `application.rb`:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
#config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
#config.assets.enabled = true
```

UPDATE：
[image]

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you execute the task locally for a more detailed log?

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` please?

Answer (score 2):

In your config/environments/production.rb, change

config.assets.js_compressor = true

to

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

And it will work!